# Java find superscript character equivalent of a character

Tags: java, superscript

I want to know the superscript unicode value of a given character in Java.

For Example:

If the inputted String is 'CAT', I want the result as unicode values for superscript 'C' superscript 'A' and superscript 'T'.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Not every unicode character have corresponding superscipt value. Possibly you will need some kind of markup.

Comment: No Problem. If we talk about basic characters like A-Z or a-z and 0-9 then?

Answer (score 0):

This is the list of [most commonly used subscript/superscripts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf)

```
Superscripts
See also superscript Latin letters in the Spacing Modifier
Letters block starting at 02B0.
2070 ⁰ SUPERSCRIPT ZERO
≈ <super> 0030 0
2071 i SUPERSCRIPT LATIN SMALL LETTER I
• functions as a modifier letter
≈ <super> 0069 i
2072 " <reserved>
→ 00B2 ²  superscript two
2073 " <reserved>
→ 00B3 ³  superscript three
2074 ⁴ SUPERSCRIPT FOUR
≈ <super> 0034 4
2075 ⁵ SUPERSCRIPT FIVE
≈ <super> 0035 5
2076 ⁶ SUPERSCRIPT SIX
≈ <super> 0036 6
2077 ⁷ SUPERSCRIPT SEVEN
≈ <super> 0037 7
2078 ⁸ SUPERSCRIPT EIGHT
≈ <super> 0038 8
2079 ⁹ SUPERSCRIPT NINE
≈ <super> 0039 9
207A ⁺ SUPERSCRIPT PLUS SIGN
≈ <super> 002B +
207B ⁻ SUPERSCRIPT MINUS
≈ <super> 2212 −
207C ⁼ SUPERSCRIPT EQUALS SIGN
≈ <super> 003D =
207D ⁽ SUPERSCRIPT LEFT PARENTHESIS
≈ <super> 0028 (
207E ⁾ SUPERSCRIPT RIGHT PARENTHESIS
≈ <super> 0029 )
207F ⁿ SUPERSCRIPT LATIN SMALL LETTER N
• functions as a modifier letter
≈ <super> 006E n
```

Hope this helps you.